# How to pass parameters in window.open for return URL:

Tags: visualforce

I have one string variable which I need to pass for return url. I am not able to pass that in my url.

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!memList}" var="list" id="pbt1" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Edit" width="100px">
        <apex:commandLink onclick="window.open('/{!list.Id}/e?retURL={!Event.Id}')"  value="Edit"  id="edit" style="text-decoration:none;color:#3399CC;"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

Controller:

```
public class ControllerExt(){
    public string passParameter;
    public ControllerExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
     {
        events = (Event)controller.getRecord();        
     }
}
```

Here passParameter is the string which I need to pass as url.

Answer (score 1):

Set the value to the URLFOR for the Event View:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!list.id}/e?retURL={!URLFOR($Action.Event.View, Event.id)}">click me</apex:outPutLink>
```

Here is a working VF page using contact as an example in case the above does not function as expected

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">

<apex:outputLink value="/{!contact.id}/e?retURL={!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, contact.Accountid)}">click me</apex:outPutLink>

</apex:page>
```

To add parameters to the URL add parameters like:

```
[param1="value1", param2="value2"]
```

After the ID like:

```
URLFOR($Action.Account.View, contact.Accountid,[param1="value1", param2="value2"])
```

Comment: Actually I need to return to vf page with some parameters... Which I guess we can not do it with URLFOR function.

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper - That was not your question NOR was it what was in your example. See updated example. If you override the View button on the event ID the it will take you to the VF Page. I have NO idea what VF page your are trying to hit as your example does not show any vf page being redirected to. You should accept this answer to close the question and open a new question I think.

Comment: are you getting any errors?